# AS3:How display ByteArray upload percentage?

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I have used ShineMP3 to record sound. Now I'm trying to upload the mp3 file to server. Here is my AS3 code:

```
function onWavClick(e:MouseEvent)
{
  var sba:ByteArray = mp3Encoder.mp3Data; 
  var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://localhost/upload.php');
  req.contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
  req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
  req.data = sba;           
  var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(req);
}
```

How can I display a percentage of upload, and if it was complete and successfully go to next frame?

Thanks.

Comment: Hm, I believe URLLoader has a "progress" event and bytesLoaded + bytesTotal properties. See if those work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing the `URLRequest` in the constructor of your `URLLoader`, use the URLLoader's `load()` method. There really is no occasion you should pass the request through the constructor, as it starts the request immediately and can complete before you are able to attach an event listener at times. Always follow this process:

1. Instantiate URLLoader and URLRequest
2. Attach event listeners and set properties on both
3. Call `load()` using the URLRequest

This will allow you to attach a `ProgressEvent` event of type `PROGRESS`, which will include a `bytesTotal` and a `bytesLoaded` property when it is dispatched. You can use these to display the percentage however you want. You can also attach `Event.COMPLETE`, which will fire when the upload is finished.

```
function onWavClick(e:MouseEvent)
{
   var sba:ByteArray = mp3Encoder.mp3Data; 
   var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(URL);
   req.contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
   req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
   req.data = sba;           
   var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
   loader.addEventListener( ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler );
   loader.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler );
   loader.load( req );
}

function progressHandler( e:ProgressEvent ):void {
    trace( e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal ); // output: progress, as a decimal from 0 to 1
}

function completeHandler( Event ):void {
    // download/upload is complete
}
```

Comment: Thanks.It works. I have another question! How I can assign a name for _sba_ file because there is many recorded files? Thanks again.

Comment: Because you uploading the data directly from memory, there is no filename as it does not reside in a file system. You will have to handle do that in your server-side script.

Comment: Can I do something like this before uploading:                 `var   namereq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/upload.php");
 namereq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
 var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
 var file_name:String = 's1';
 variables.nam = file_nam;
 namereq.data = variables;
 loader.load(namreq);`

Comment: and on PHP: `$file_name = $_POST['nam'];`

Comment: No, as someone else's upload could begin between the two requests, meaning there is no way to guarantee filename. Additionally, the name, as you have it set up currently, would be the same for every user. Instead, look into passing additional variables with your data (admittedly not easy) or creating a random filename on the server-side (I tend to use `uniqid()` combined with some sort of random string to guarantee a unique filename)

Comment: So if I pass the users name who logged in, from PHP to AS3, I think it possible.Isn't it?

Comment: Sure, but you have to deal with sending data alongside your ByteArray, which isn't easy in AS3. Additionally, that will limit each user to a single file. You **must** implement a unique filename scheme system server-side.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39200/discussion-between-amir-and-josh-janusch)

Comment: The common solution for passing both data and metadata (filename, extra variables and stuff) is to use 'multipart/form-data' as your request contentType. You'll need to have an upload script that knows how to read it, of course. More details and a helper class over here: http://marstonstudio.com/2007/10/19/how-to-take-a-snapshot-of-a-flash-movie-and-automatically-upload-the-jpg-to-a-server-in-three-easy-steps/

Comment: @jpop I tried that method with an app I built in July. I wasn't able to get it successfully working (the upload would completely fail, no data was received whatsoever). That's why I kept saying it was a pain to get to work. I ended up using `File.upload()` instead, which drives me nuts but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion could be this PHP Upload Progress bar:

http://www.johnboyproductions.com/php-upload-progress-bar/